# UITextView/UILabel with background but with spacing between lines

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

How can I achieve this kind of style in iOS?

[image]

I tried using `NSAttributedString` and setting `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` as `blackColor` but then it doesn't have a `clearColor` space between the lines. I also tried to set a `lineSpacing` to the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` but still, the style looks like one big black block.

I just need a hint in which way to go... thanks!

In other words, not something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research I found the best solution for what I needed.
The solution below is only iOS7+.

First we add this to `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` of your `UITextView` subclass.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect    

    /// Position each line behind each line.
    [self.layoutManager enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length) usingBlock:^(CGRect rect, CGRect usedRect, NSTextContainer *textContainer, NSRange glyphRange, BOOL *stop) {

        /// The frame of the rectangle.
        UIBezierPath *rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(usedRect.origin.x, usedRect.origin.y+3, usedRect.size.width, usedRect.size.height-4)];

        /// Set the background color for each line.
        [UIColor.blackColor setFill];

        /// Build the rectangle.
        [rectanglePath fill];
    }];
 }];
```

Then we set the line spacing for the UITextView:

```
- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return 15;
}
```

The method above is only called if you set the `NSLayoutManagerDelegate`. You could do that in your `init`, `initWithFrame` and `initWithCode` methods like this:

```
self.layoutManager.delegate = self;
```

Also don't forget to declare that your subclass is a delegate in your `.h` file:

```
@interface YOUR_SUBCLASS_OF_UITEXTVIEW : UITextView <NSLayoutManagerDelegate>
```

Comment: thanks but its working for only two lines i want to be use for multiple line of text.@Fabio

Comment: Can you please provide a swift version  aswell ?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani: there's a Swift version processing an entire text if you still need it ⟹ stackoverflow.com/a/59216224/3825084

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3 version** of @Fabio's solution :

```
class splitedTextView: UITextView, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layoutManager.delegate = self
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.text.characters.count)) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, Bool) in
            let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: usedRect.origin.x, y: usedRect.origin.y+3, width: usedRect.size.width, height: usedRect.size.height-4))
            UIColor.black.setFill()
            rectanglePath.fill()
        }
    }

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, lineSpacingAfterGlyphAt glyphIndex: Int, withProposedLineFragmentRect rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }
}
```

You can also create a variable inside your `textView` subclass to manage rectangle's color :

```
var color: UIColor?
```

And then use it instead of default black in your `textView` subclass :

```
self.color?.setFill()
```

Also if you do that, don't forget to use `setNeedsDisplay()` to redraw your `textView` and apply your custom color.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 11 attributed string has a problem with this kind of UI behavior. I've created UITextView subclass with space and bgColor property. Hope this helps too. The answer is just an extension to @Fabio solution.

```
class SpacingTextView: UITextView, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {

private var textHolder: String?
var spacing: CGFloat = 3
var bgColor: UIColor = .white

override var attributedText: NSAttributedString! {
    didSet {
        self.textHolder = self.attributedText.string
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override var text: String! {
    didSet {
        self.textHolder = self.attributedText.string
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    self.configure()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.configure()
}

private func configure() {
    self.layoutManager.delegate = self
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    guard let txt = self.textHolder else {
        return
    }
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: txt.count)

    self.layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: textRange) { (rect, usedRect, _, _, _) in
        var bgRect = usedRect
        bgRect.origin.y += self.spacing / 2
        bgRect.size.height -= self.spacing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bgRect)
        self.bgColor.setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()
        bezierPath.close()
    }
}

func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
                   lineSpacingAfterGlyphAt glyphIndex: Int, withProposedLineFragmentRect rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
    return rect.size.height
}

func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
                   shouldUse action: NSLayoutManager.ControlCharacterAction,
                   forControlCharacterAt charIndex: Int) -> NSLayoutManager.ControlCharacterAction {
    return .lineBreak
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a new blank line with a paragraph style with the desired line height. In my Swift example, I just append an interlineAttributedString to the original attributedString:

```
let interlineStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
interlineStyle.maximumLineHeight = 5.0
let interlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: interlineStyle])
attributedString.appendAttributedString(interlineAttributedString)
```

The extra \n can also be part of the original attributedString. In that case, you would use `addAttribute` with the appropriate range.

I tested on iOS 9 only, but I'm pretty sure it works well on previous iOS versions. It works perfectly in a UITextView. It is much easier to implement than using many UILabels or drawing the background rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** :

For your requirment you need to use `different UILabel` for `each line` and `manage spacing` by `setting frame`.

---

This is working for me to have `spacing` between `lines` in `multiline UILabel`.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourlblText.text];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:16];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:style
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, yourlblText.text.length)];
yourlblText.attributedText = attrString;
```

Also check [iOS 6 multiline label line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091724/1106035)

Comment: Hi @Prince, thanks for your answer! But your code generates exactly what you see in the second image I just added to my question. There is no transparent space between the lines.

Comment: Hey @Prince, thanks for the answer again! Your solution creating different `UILabel` is very dirty but I guess I have to go with this if I want to fulfill the requirements. Still searching for a better one. But thanks for providing a solution anyway! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to create a UIView and add the label on it, constrain to Vertical top and the calculate the number of lines using the font size and line height and then create a CALayer for each line and add those to the UIView.

You can check my implementation [here](https://github.com/anoop4real/UILabelStyles)

```
    func setBorderLabel() {
       let str = "This is label style with solid highlight and have gap between the texts, uses a combination of UIView and UILabel, you can have borders also per line... check comments in the code"
       let trimmedString = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

       let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: trimmedString)
       borderLabel.attributedText = string

       let labelWidth: CGFloat = borderLabel.frame.size.width
       var lineCount: Float = 0.0
       let textSize = CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
       let rHeight: Float = Float(borderLabel.sizeThatFits(textSize).height)
       //var rWidth: Int = lroundf(Float(borderLabel.sizeThatFits(textSize).width))
       let charSize: Float = Float(borderLabel.font.lineHeight)
       lineCount =  (rHeight / charSize).rounded()
       var count = 0
       // This needs a bit of trial and error, you need to play with the FONT_SIZE value to get the desired effect
       for i in stride(from: 0, to: Int(borderLabel.frame.size.height) , by: FONT_SIZE) {
           if count >= Int(lineCount){
               break
           }
           let border = CALayer()
           border.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
           border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i), width: borderLabel.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(FONT_SIZE - 1) )
           // Uncomment the below lines to have borders per line.
           //border.borderWidth = 1.0
           //border.cornerRadius = 6.0
           border.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764741, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.3529411852, alpha: 1)
           borderLabel.layer.addSublayer(border)
           bgView.layer.insertSublayer(border, at: 0)
           count = count + 1
           borderLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
       }

   }
```