# TextKit - UILabel with background and spacing

Tags: swift, uilabel, textkit, nslayoutmanager

I've been working on something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360006/uitextview-uilabel-with-background-but-with-spacing-between-lines).

Everything was working fine until I've found out a string input that causes an issue

[image: Case where the issue is present]

The input string is "This is a long titlessss \n Withssssssss"

Basically, it seems like the "long" word fits the space but for some reason, it is being drawn in the next line.

When I set a new attributed text, I'm always updating the textStorage in this way

```
textStorage.setAttributedString(attributedText)
```

My UILabel's subclass calls

`layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: range) { (_, usedRect, _, glyphRange, _) in` inside `drawText(in rect:)`

Here glyphRange returns `location 0 and length 15` for the first LineFragments ( so until long ) and the rect size is what you see drawn in the picture because it's the one I use to create the bezier path.

These are the settings for all the object of TextKit

```
let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
layoutManager.usesFontLeading = false
layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = true

translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
backgroundColor = .clear
lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

I've tried everything. Some delegate methods, moving the logic all around.. I can't understand why that string is being drawn in the next line.

Comment: Did you try and write your text in a UITextView instead of a UILabel?